# Activate profile when finishing release using jgitflow Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I have a Maven profile `documentation` that I want to get activated when running `mvn jgitflow:release-finish`. I know that I can do:

```
mvn jgitflow:release-finish -Pdocumentation
```

because the documentation of the plugin states:

> automatically copies any profiles (-P) and user-properties (-D) passed on the command line to the forked maven process when building

But that means that you cannot forget to add this profile manually.

**Objective**: I would like to be able to configure Maven so that this profile becomes active automatically (Or that I somehow can activate my profile when the 'release' profile is active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`jgitflow:release-finish`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/goals/release-finish) goal actually uses a default option `useReleaseProfile` defining:

> Whether to use the release profile that adds sources and javadocs to the released artifact, if appropriate. If set to `true`, the plugin sets the property `performRelease` to `true`, which activates the profile "release-profile", which is inherited from the super pom.

This option has default value to `true`, hence when executing this goal will by default set the `performRelease` property to `true`.

Note that the *release profile* mentioned above is defined by the [super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html), which is actually used by this plugin but also by the `maven-release-plugin` via the similar [`useReleaseProfile`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#useReleaseProfile) option.

You can then activate your [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) based on this option as well, as following:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>documentation</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>performRelease</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This means that you can still esplicitely activate it via the `-P` option and that it will be automatically activated by the goal as well.

Comment: Is there a way to specify which profile to use? What if we don't want to run the plugin executions in the super POM, just those we have configured? I also note the comment in the linked super POM "<!-- NOTE: The release profile will be removed from future versions of the super POM -->"